# Impossible to use BaseGameActivity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) but I still cannot use BaseGameActivity.

I installed the Library through SDK manager and I added this in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08'
}
```

I also edited AndroidManifest
Then I used "Sync Project With Gradle Files". I have no errors but I cannot had any of these

```
import gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
```

-> Cannot resolve symbol 'gms' and Cannot resolve symbole 'example'

Now I'm stuck.

Comment: Does your project build from the command line?

Comment: Nope, I do everything in Android Studio.

Comment: You need to download [BaseGameUtils](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) separely from the SDK download of Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You need to download BaseGameUtils separely from the SDK download of Google Play Services"

Yes that was that in fact. Thanks.